# Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'

Tags: mysql-workbench

When I tried to copy the text from before the first comma in the first column to the second column using the following command:

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET second_column = SUBSTRING_INDEX(first_column, ‘,’, 1);
```

I got the error message:
*Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'*

What is going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error came from copying and pasting the command from a non-programming text editor (i.e. Word):
The quotes around the delimiter were changed from two normal single quotes (') and (') to left and right single quotes (‘) and (’).

Changing the delimiter to two normal single quotes around the delimiter solved the problem:

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET second_column = SUBSTRING_INDEX(first_column, ',', 1);
```